# The method onClick(View) of type oddg must override a superclass method?

Tags: java, android, overriding

I am occurring error like:

> "The method onClick(View) of type oddg must override a superclass
>   method".

I am confused where exactly error has occurred.
Can you please guide me, what exactly error is?

```
public class oddg extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        int increment;
        int maximum ;
        private static final String TAG = "ServicesDemo";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main1);
            Button startbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbtn);
            startbtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        { }
}
```

This is my code...
Thanks in Advance--
Onkar

Comment: Did you use the @Override annotation on a method that doesn't have a signature matching one from a parent or implemented interface?  At any rate, were you to post complete minimal code necessary to replicate your problem, folks would better be able to help you.

Comment: @thane i have edited my Q. to code,yes i have used @Override annotation,nut what i want to do for it,please guide me..

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're compiler settings are set to Java 1.5 instead of Java 1.6. Since Java 1.6 the annotation @Override is not only possible for inherited methods from a superclass but also for implemented methods from an interface. But if your compiler is still set to 1.5 the problem is that he will check if you're overwriting a method from a super class. In your example this is not the case since you're implementing a method from an interface.

As a side note it would be good to follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) in your code. So all classes begin with an upper case letter.

Comment: If you're using Eclipse go to Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler and the change Compiler compliance level to 1.6

Comment: I am getting same waring with java 1.7 . Is int it starnge !

Comment: Just to add mine, after this change restart Eclipse. Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but It still showed me an error, even after changing to 1.6. Thus I had to change to 1.7 and try ( inspite of the warning) and it worked.

Comment: Right click on your project => Properties =>  Java Compiler => change Compiler compliance level to 1.6 or 1.7

Answer (score 9):

I had the same trouble and I fixed it like this:

- Open Project settings->Java Compiler
- Set **Enable Project Specific Settings** to `disable`

Answer (score 3):

This isn't directly appropriate to this question but you will also get this error if you haven't declared `implements OnClickListener` on the class declaration.

```
// Wrong
public class aClass extends Activity {
}
// Right
public class aClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
}
```

This may seem dum to the more experienced coder but I'm new to this and it fooled me.

Answer (score 2):

Read about [`@Override`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation. It means, that once you have annotated the method with `@Override`, the compiler checks if it really an overrided method, and shows an error if its not.

Also, you have to have Language Level 6 in order to use it with interface implementing methods. In IDEA you can do it via Project Setup.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I found the solution writing well the import.

I replaced

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener; //(wrong)
```

for

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Comment: This is the solution, a bad import

Comment: Correct, i also resolved issue using your solution. my vote 1+

Answer (score 0):

"RoflcoptrException" is right! You shoud set java compiler to 1.6
Project properties -> Java compiler ->1.6

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio , you can also override your method by pressing **ctrl+O** or just go to **code-> Overide** and override appropriate method .
It will automatically override your method .