# can not override showDialog in Activity tab

Tags: android, overriding

Trying to downgrade my appl from android 2.2 (API 8) down to android 2.1 (API7), I'm facing some issues with dialog boxes. Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6259798/461212), I'm trying to catch these exceptions but can't override the showDialog method.

I turned the Java compiler from 1.5 to 1.6 according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5776183/461212) to a similar issue, but no changes, Eclipse still returns :

> Cannot override the final method from Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements
        SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {


// ... some stuffs

    @Override // here is the issue
    public void showDialog(int dialogId) {
        try {
            super.showDialog(dialogId);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(ACTIVITY_TAG, "Error dialog");
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_ALERT:
            // Create out AlertDialog
            Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(msg);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton(GOTO_BOOK, new OkOnClickListener());
            builder.setNegativeButton(STAY_HERE, new CancelOnClickListener());
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            break;
        case DIALOG_ONCREATE:
            // Create out AlertDialog during the "onCreate" method (only "Ok"
            // button)
            Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
            builder2.setMessage(msg);
            builder2.setCancelable(false);
            builder2.setPositiveButton(GO_BACK, new OkOnClickListener());

            AlertDialog dialog2 = builder2.create();
            dialog2.show();
            break;
        }

        return super.onCreateDialog(id);

    }

    // ... some stuffs

    }
```

Comment: I dont think you can do it, the answer posted need not work, its not a working code. And the api has always been final. So you cannot override showDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onCreateDialog should not show the dialog , show part will be done by framework. All you need to do is return the correct dialog.

Remove the override part. You dont need a workaround for this issue. There is problem in your code

Remove

```
dialog.show();
```

Also Instead of this

```
return super.onCreateDialog(id);
```

use

```
return dialog;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a **final method** of activity so you can't override this . If you want to show dialog just call the method.

```
showDialog(ID);
```

Comment: Thx, I'm already using showDialog(ID); later in the code. But I'm facing issues so I'd like to isolate that exception overriding the showDialog method, but looks like it's an API final method so can not be overriden..  So I guess I'll have to handle this differrently using my own showDialog method.